# Warnings: Array to string conversion, undefined property in PHP 8.1 trying to call a property of an object (worked in PHP 5.5)

Tags: php, arrays, object, braces

> [NOTE: I **solved** this problem in the course of drafting the
> question, but figured I would proceed with posting it for future
> reference, since my extensive searching on the warnings delivered did
> not provide the solution and I figure this might help someone in the
> future.]

I have a class `Thing` that has properties `$subthing_1`, `$subthing_2`, `$subthing_3`, all of which are objects:

```
class Thing {
...
  public $subthing_1; // object of type Subthing
  public $subthing_2; // object of type Subthing
  public $subthing_3; // object of type Subthing
...
}
```

If I want to get a particular subthing in an instance of Thing, I can do:

`$thing->subthing_1`

and this works just fine to deliver that subthing.  But I want to generalize which of the subthings are called, so I have a routine that gets the name of a particular subthing, either 'subthing_1', 'subthing_2', or 'subthing_3', and stores it in a string in an array element.  Thus, `$subthings[4]` has string value 'subthing_1', for example, and

`$thing->$subthings[4]`

should deliver exactly the same as `$thing->subthing_1`.

If I do

`var_dump($subthings[4]);`

the result is

`string(10) "subthing_1"`

and for

`var_dump($thing);`

the result is

```
object(Thing)#4 (87) {
...
  ["subthing_1"]=>
  object(Category)#59 (12) {
...
  }
...
}
```

Which is all fine and good.  However, when I try to do this:

`var_dump($thing->$subthings[4]);`

I get this:

> **Warning**: Array to string conversion ...
>
> **Warning**: Undefined property: Thing::$Array ...
>
> **Warning**: Trying to access array offset on value of type null ...

This confused me for a long time, because I couldn't see where an array was being converted to a string.  `$subthings[4]` is clearly a string, as indicated by `var_dump($subthings[4])`, not an array.

These warnings are appearing in PHP 8.1 for code that worked just fine in PHP 5.5.

Eventually I reasoned that there must have been a syntax interpretation change somewhere between these two PHP versions.

Whereas in PHP 5.5, `$thing->$subthings[4]` is interpreted as `$thing->{$subthings[4]}`, in PHP 8.1 `$thing->$subthings[4]` is interpreted as `{$thing->$subthings}[4]`.

I have searched high and low for documentation of this change, but I guess I am not hitting on the right keywords.  I hope someone here can supply an answer for where this change is documented.

Comment: It's great that you solved the problem, but it's preferable to add that as an actual answer rather than making it part of the question.

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation, by the way: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **SOLUTION** is to surround the arrays with curly braces to enforce the expected (and formerly default) parse ordering:

`$thing->{$subthings[4]}`

As pointed out by Don't Panic, this evaluation syntax change is documented here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect